# DrawCats var how to define it

Tags: javascript

I just start to looking deeply in JavaScript.. when i start analyze and try to compile this code i just had a problem... after few minutes I gave up. Maybe somone know what is wrong with it? When I try to compile it I see Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

```
    // Draw that much cats as you wish!  
       var drawCats = function (howMuch) {  
         for (var i = 0; i < howMuch; i++) {  
            console.log(i + " =^.^=");  
          }
```

};

EDIT: OFCOURSE I put in howMuch number

```
// Draw that much cats as you wish!  
       var drawCats = function (10) {  
         for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
            console.log(i + " =^.^=");  
          }
```

Comment: That code works.

Comment: That code compiled without any errors. Please real [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Which environment are you running the code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function expression looks like this:

```
function ( argument_name, another_argument_name ) {
    /body
}
```

… where you can have any number of argument names.

The argument names are **variables** to which values as assigned when the function is **called**:

```
drawCats(10); // Here 10 is a **value**
```

You can't put a number in the definition of the function because a number is not a valid variable name

```js
// Draw that much cats as you wish!  
var drawCats = function(howMuch) {
  for (var i = 0; i < howMuch; i++) {
    console.log(i + " =^.^=");
  }
};


drawCats(10);
```